# Present ViewController Segue Transition Without Storyboard [Swift]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm relatively new to Swift and I'm trying to present a new View Controller with a fade-in as opposed to the default modal animation (appear from bottom). I am not using storyboards and I wanted to see if there's a good way to do this programmatically. I tried using modalTransitionStyle but I think I may not have implemented it properly. Here is my code:

```
    var modalStyle: UIModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    StartViewController().modalTransitionStyle = modalStyle
    presentViewController(StartViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Each time you call `StartViewController()` you are creating a new one.  Instead, put that into a constant so that you can refer to the same one:

```
let modalStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
let svc = StartViewController()
svc.modalTransitionStyle = modalStyle
presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

You can skip creating `modalStyle` and just set the `modalTransitionStyle` directly:

```
let svc = StartViewController()
svc.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```